# Create an executable .bat file for a Maven project

Tags: java

I have a maven project which runs on command line by running a script.
I want to distribute it on both Windows and Linux.
I have searched all the related posts but I didn't fully understood how I can create a .bat file for windows.

All my dependencies are copied to a folder named mavenLib
and a jar file gets created in the target folder in ubuntu using:

```
export CLASSPATH=`ls -1 target/mavenLib/* | tr '\n' ':'`target/ClientPortfolioCreator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What is the alternative in windows?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use a maven plugin called the **appassembler-maven-plugin**. This plugin generates Unix and Windows scripts and also copies all  necessary dependencies in a local folder.

The plugin's basic usage is as follows:

In the build section of the `pom.xml`, add the following configuration according to your requirements.

```
<build>  
  <plugins>  
    <plugin> 
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
      <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
      <configuration>
       <programs>  
         <program>  
            <mainClass>your.package.YourMainClass</mainClass>
            <name>TheScriptName</name>
         </program>
       </programs>   
      </configuration>  
    </plugin>  
 </plugins>
```

Then execute:

```
mvn package appassembler:assemble
```

And that's all, the plugin output is located by default in *target/appassembler*

For more detailed information, go to the plugin [homepage](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/).

Comment: I tried this and getting exception  generics are not supported in -source 1.3

Comment: I tried with source 1.5 then got [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.mojo:appassembler-maven-plugin:pom:1.5' in repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)

Comment: Seems like maven cannot find the plugin in that repository, try again adding http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ as a repository directly.