# How to create .bat files using Maven Appassembler that runs a JAR?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, jar

I'm trying to create a `.bat` file to run my generated executable JAR file. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392509/6042824) method of creating `.bat` files for running a project. So, I read up on the plugin [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html) and added the following to my `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <assembleDirectory>${assembleDir}</assembleDirectory>
        <generateRepository>false</generateRepository>
        <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
        <configurationDirectory>conf</configurationDirectory>
        <copyConfigurationDirectory>false</copyConfigurationDirectory>
        <programs>
            <program>
                <mainClass>com.companyname.tests.TestRunner</mainClass>
                <id>AutoConfigTest</id>
            </program>
        </programs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And, yes, as the name suggests, this JAR contains JUnit test cases.

I prevented the plugin from unpacking JARs and creating the `repo` folder and set that to my already generated `lib` folder, which contains all the JARs(executables and the dependencies). The `.bat` file is being generated but, when running it, I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.companyname.tests.TestRunner
```

Also, I want the command prompt to stay after execution. In this case it is closing immediately. Maybe its because I'm getting an error. I'm not sure.

So, got into searching again and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15228501/6042824). But as the accepted answer suggests, my `pom.xml` already contains -

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

The assembled directory is -

```
AutoConfigTest
 |
 |--bin
 |   `- contains the .bat file
 |--conf
 |   `- contains the property files and other configuration files
 |--lib
     `- contains all the JARs
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, that [question you mention](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15228501/6042824) looks exactly like yours. The accepted solution is strange, as `jar` is default packaging. Did you try the other solutions and suggestions? It seems there are several things that can go wrong and each other answer tackles one of those things.

Comment: What is the content of the generated `.bat` file? Does any `.jar` file in `lib/` contain your class `com.companyname.tests.TestRunner`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes, the jar which contains `com.companyname.tests.TestRunner` in present in the `lib` folder. I've checked it.

Comment: @BileshGanguly I assume it is not at the place the script `AutoConfigTest.bat` expect it. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @SubOptimal I've already added the dependencies to the classpath. Please take a look at the generated batch file. I've updated the question.

Comment: What does `jar tf target\appassembler\lib\AutomatedConfigurationTestingTests-1.jar | findstr TestRunner.class` return?

Comment: @SubOptimal The main class isn't in `AutomatedConfigurationTestingTests-1.jar`. That only I mentioned in the comment on your answer. You are correct in pointing out that the main class isn't visible to the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. [@SubOptimal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333222/suboptimal) was correct in pointing out that the main class isn't visible to the batch file.

For some reason, the test JAR file (which contains the main class) isn't being added to the classpath variable of the batch file. As a result, whenever I ran the batch file, I was getting the error mentioned in the question.

I went back to the documentation and found [this](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html#useWildcardClassPath).

> Sometimes it happens that you have many dependencies which means having a very long classpath, and becomes too long (in particular on Windows based platforms). This option can help in such situation. If you activate this option, your classpath contains only a classpath wildcard (`REPO/*`). But be aware that this works only in combination with Java 1.6 and above and with `repositoryLayout` `flat`.

So, instead of adding individual JAR files into the path, I added the whole `lib` directory to the classpath by adding the following to the `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    ...
    <configuration>
        ...
        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
        <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>
        ...
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

I could do this because the repository layout of `lib` was already flat. There were no hierarchies. No other change was required. The batch file now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's related to (from the [README.md](https://github.com/mojohaus/appassembler/README.md))

> All dependencies and the artifact of the project itself are placed **in a generated Maven repository** in a defined assemble directory. All artifacts (dependencies + the artifact from the project) are added to the classpath in the generated bin scripts.

In your `pom.xml` you prevent the generation of that repository. So you need to ensure that the artifact from the project is copied at the expected place.

Assuming following project settings

```
<groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
<artifactId>Maven-AppAssembler</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

the artifact is expected to be at (the CLASSPATH setting in the scripts `bin/AutoConfigTest`)

```
"$REPO"/com/companyname/Maven-AppAssembler/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Maven-AppAssembler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

where `$REPO` resolve to `target/appassembler/lib`.

Comment: I think I found the error. You are correct in pointing out that the main class isn't visible to the batch file. For some reason, the test jar file (which contains the main class) isn't being added to the classpath variable of the batch file.